# How to get the result separated by ,?

Tags: php

```
$getMusicList =explode(',', $event[0]['even_music']);
            print_r($getMusicList);
```

this line gives

```
    Array
    (
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 12
    [2] => 5
    )

      $exeGetMusic1 = array();
        foreach ($getMusicList as $kk => $musicList) {

             $getMusic = "select event_music_nam FROM et_mc 
                 WHERE eventmusic_id='".$musicList."'";
             $exeGetMusic = execute_query($getMusic, false, "select");
             $exeGetMusic1[] = $exeGetMusic;



        }
        print_r($exeGetMusic1);
```

this line gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [event_music_nam] => Alternative
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [event_music_nam] => Classics
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [event_music_nam] => Country/Folk
        )

)
```

But I  want to the final ans should be like this

```
Alternative,Classics,Country/Folk
```

plz help.
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When there is only one item in sub array then why are you creating sub array at all, manage them in single dimension array. follow the below

Replace the last line of foreach `$exeGetMusic1[] = $exeGetMusic;`

with the line below

```
$exeGetMusic1[] = $exeGetMusic['event_music_nam'];
```

and replace `print_r($exeGetMusic1);` with this line

```
echo implode(',',$exeGetMusic1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output = array();
foreach ($exeGetMusic1 as $music)
    $output[] = $music['event_music_nam'];
echo implode(',', $output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = implode(',', array_map(function ($item) {
  return $item['event_music_nam'];
}, $exeGetMusic1));
```

Or (if you don't care how `$execGetMusic1` looks like) replace

```
$exeGetMusic1[] = $exeGetMusic;
```

within the loop with

```
$exeGetMusic1[] = $exeGetMusic['event_music_nam'];
```

and then `implode()` everything together

```
$result = implode(',', $exeGetMusic1);
```