# Get results separated by commas

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get the results separated by commas from my PHP snippet in my Wordpress (wp shortcode)

The problem is that only the last record is fetched from the database.

```
datescanned    host    
2019-03-01     10.1.1.1
2019-03-01     10.1.1.2
2019-03-01     10.1.1.3
```

I want my output to be:

10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.2, 10.1.1.3

My original code was:

```
function get_sss1_last_scannedip() {
global $wpdb; 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT host FROM bitnami_wordpress.sss1_latest WHERE CLIENT ='$current_user->user_login'"); 

 print_r('<div style="color:#fff;text-align:left;font-weight:500;font-size:12px">Target: ' . $result . '</div>');    

} 
add_shortcode('sss1_last_scannedip', 'get_sss1_last_scannedip');
```

This is getting the last result only...

After searching this site
[How to get the result separated by ,?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776427/how-to-get-the-result-separated-by)

I came up with this code but still not working

```
function get_sss1_last_scannedip() {
global $wpdb; 

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$output = array();
foreach ($output as $result)
$output[] = $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT host FROM bitnami_wordpress.sss1_latest WHERE CLIENT ='$current_user->user_login'"); 
echo implode(',', $output);


  print_r('<div style="color:#fff;text-align:left;font-weight:500;font-size:12px">Target: ' . $output . '</div>');    

}

add_shortcode('sss1_last_scannedip', 'get_sss1_last_scannedip');
```

Any help would be greatly and much appreciated!

** UPDATE **

I changed the following line and now I get all the results!  However, I do get all the duplicate ones as well :(

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(host) as Host FROM bitnami_wordpress.sss1_latest WHERE CLIENT ='$current_user->user_login' order by host group by host");
```

How can I get only one occurrence of the same field value?

Now I get:

10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.11,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.24,10.211.105.25,10.211.105.26,10.211.105.27,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,192.168.211.131,

10.211.105.11 comes up multiple times, I just want one time.

I thought GROUP BY host will suffice or ..

```
...  AND  host = ( SELECT max(host) FROM bitnami_wordpress.sss1_latest )");
```

The above line doesn't return anything...

HELP!

Regards,
Nathalie

Answer (score 0):

You should add a comma as seperator, when you try to implode it with a comma as seperator.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT host FROM bitnami_wordpress.sss1_latest WHERE CLIENT ='$current_user->user_login'") . ',';
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by adding DICTINCT to group_concat

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT host) as host FROM bitnami_wordpress.sss1_latest WHERE CLIENT ='$current_user->user_login'");
```